# Where to place "constants" in cocoa

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, constants

I communicate with a json api in my cocoa (touch) app.

As a response I get something like this:

```
"wh": {
 "1": ["11.30 - 15.00"], 
 "3": ["11.30 - 15.00"], 
 "2": ["12.00 - 14.00", "17.30 - 23.00"], 
 "5": ["11.30 - 15.00"], 
 "4": ["11.30 - 15.00"]
},
```

Keys 0 to 6 reflect the weekdays (Monday == 0, Tuesday = 1, ....)

To map this I have a NSArray:

```
weekdays = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Montag",
       @"Dienstag",
       @"Mittwoch",
       @"Donnerstag",
       @"Freitag",
       @"Samstag",
       @"Sonntag", nil];
```

I need this in two viewcontrollers - currently set in the viewWillAppear. :(

So my question(s):

1. Where/When should I set this weekdays array?
2. How to access it in the viewcontrollers?
3. Any suggestions?

Comment: thx to everybody for your very helpful answerS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a singleton to store that kind of information, here is an example:

http://getsetgames.com/2009/08/30/the-objective-c-singleton/

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use the `NSDateFormatter` class? You can use it to get localized days of the wekk names for any language.

Answer (score 1):

The way I handle constants in my apps...

1) Create a Common.h file, put it in your Resources directory.

2) Define all the constants you want in there.

```
#define STATE_INDEX [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"AL", @"AK", @"AZ", ... nil]
#define NSDATEFORMATTER_WITH_TIME_FORMAT @"dd/MM/yyyy : HH:mm:ss"
#define PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT 216
```

3) Make sure to...

```
#import "Common.h"
```

in the code files you want to use the constants in.

Comment: When the compiler expands the defines (STATE_INDEX for example), isn't it going to result in an NSArray being created (and autoreleased) for each occurrence of STATE_INDEX?  It's likely not a big deal in most cases, but could be a problem if your NSArray is huge, or used very frequently.  A global as you suggested in the Question is much nicer in this regard.

Or is the compiler smart enough to create one NSArray object and share it?  I'd be impressed if it were!

Comment: I do something like... (arrayStates defined elsewhere) [arrayStates addObjectsFromArray:STATE_INDEX];  I believe it acts just like it would if you typed it out, simple text replacement.

Comment: You can also include the `Common.h` file in your precompiled header file.

Answer (score 0):

You could rely in a .strings file:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:key value:key table:@"Weekdays"]
```